# How to show a message box on center of screen?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, ajax

I have a asp.net solution that uses ajax. One of the features using update progress panel is that the contents are only revealed when an ajax request is going on in the background.

So I want to basically show a black transparent background which stops the user from doing anything, and also display a box in the center of the screen that says please wait, and has a loading gif.

I was able to get the black background using this:

```
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="AjaxAnimation" runat="server">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <center>
                                <%-- <asp:Image ID="loadingImage" runat="server" src="/_layouts/images/PDFLibrary/ajax-loader.gif"/> --%>
                                <div class="dim"></div>
                            </center>
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Css

```
.dim 
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:100 !important;
    background-color:black; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;       /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.75;           /* fx, safari, opera */
}
```

But how can I have a box in the center of the screen?

Comment: Which one is your box?  I'm assuming `dim` is that transparent background.

Comment: Currently the div tag with the class `dim` makes the background transparent. But I want to use it for the message box as well. If not I can just add another div tag or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as following?:

```
<div class="dim" runat="server">
    <span class="msg">Please wait...</span>
</div>

.dim
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:100 !important;
    background-color:black; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;       /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.75;           /* fx, safari, opera */
}

.dim .msg {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px
    height: 100px;
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Is `.your_loading_div` supposed to be `.dim`? I dont see `your_loading_div` in the html.

Comment: Edited, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: When I try this, the please wait text is horizontally aligned which is good, but is vertically aligned on the top, it should be in the center.

Comment: Please change the `position` on `.dim` to `fixed` from `relative` like you had originally.  I realized this when trying out in the jsfiddle; I've added the link to it in my previous comment.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle where I have that code?  It is vertically and horizontally centred in Firefox, Chrome and IE for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use position:absolute and negative margin.

```
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-100px;
margin-left:-100px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
```

Please have a look my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qd6eR/)